# What is the best practice to define consistently from access layer to listitems

Tags: c#, asp.net, class

I am quite new to ASP.Net / webforms and this might sound a basic question, if I am defining a client class in webforms ASP.Net that will hold ClientId, ClientName and Type of Client (Proposed, FullClient, Dead) I am not sure of the best way to make this consistent from the Access Layer/database, which will normally hold a type of 'P' - Proposed F - FullClient and 'D' for Dead to the definition of the client class through to creating a listitem for setting up a client in html of the possible choices which requires a option and description where I believe the class uses an enum? If you could point me to a simple would be great.

Thanks in Advance.

Answer (score 1):

Just use an `enum`, you can store things like that in a Shared project that all other projects have references too, something like YourProject.Utilities.

Here's the `enum`:

```
public enum ClientType
{
    [Description("Proposed")]
    Proposed = 1,

    [Description("Dead")]
    Dead = 2,

    [Description("Full Client")]
    FullClient = 3
}
```